# "Virtual" or "view" branch in git (on github)

Tags: git, github, workflow

We're a small organization that uses github. We have a pretty simple workflow; feature and fix branches are made off of origin/develop, and pull requests are opened back onto develop when the developer thinks the branch is ready to be merged. We then do code review and QA.

This often means that there are three or four open PRs at a time, and there's a 1-5 day lag between when a PR is opened and when it is approved by the team and merged into develop.

Locally, I've started keeping a 'future' branch, which is basically just develop + any open PRs. This lets me have my own nightly build be as complete as possible, and lets me catch possible conflicts a bit earlier.

So: I'm interested in making this `future` branch available to the rest of the team. I can see this getting a bit complicated, though: currently, if a PR is closed, I just nuke my local branch and then rebuild again from develop. This is super easy. It gets a little more complicated, though, if other people have their own local copies. I can always force-push my own working copy back up to origin, but then there will be conflicts for people who check it out.

Ideally, I could have some sort of 'virtual' branch, that just offered an up-to-date snapshot of the code base at a given time, and which people could just sort of update and build.

Does anything like this exist? Is there some other way of getting the sort of functionality I'm talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but then there will be conflicts for people who check it out.

Only if they "check it out" by merging. If they just fetch the ref and then directly check it out, there's no merging involved - they'll have exactly what's in the branch.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/future
```

The above commands will fetch the refs from the `origin` remote, and then directly check out the ref which is `origin`'s copy of `future`.

Similarly, if they want to keep a local copy, they can force update it instead of trying to merge new changes:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -B future origin/future
```

Then if you update your local branch, and want to force update the remote, you can do:

```
git push origin future --force
```